# I need help accessing info inside an object

Tags: javascript, object

Working on a Discord bot and I need the user ID, which in this case is 'xxx'. Not sure how to get it.

I've tried
n.mentions.users.User. -- n.mentions.users.User()

What I have on my app:

```
bot.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'myId'){
        msg.reply().then(n => {
            console.log(n.mentions.users);
        });
    }
})
```

What I get back:

```
Collection [Map] {
  '1803209281398201380913' => User {
    id: 'xxx',
    username: 'zzz',
    discriminator: '0000'
}
```

I expect 'xxx' but get undefined.

Comment: One message can mention multiple users. Which one do you want?

Comment: I just need the first one.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions

Comment: Solved it with: console.log(n.mentions.users.entries().next().value[1].id);

Comment: @hereticMonkey thats not a Map.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
message.mentions.users.first().id
```

Comment: msg.reply().then(n => {
            console.log(message.mentions.users.first());
        });
    }
})

Like this?

Comment: Solved it with: console.log(n.mentions.users.entries().next().value[1].id);